# Using PhoneGap/Cordova on windows phone 7 with external URL

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, plugins

I need my windows 7 Phonegap/Cordova app to load an external page on start and nothing local.

I did find a solution for iOS and android , but i cant really find something solid for windows phone 7.

Any ideas on how i could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it via **StartPageUri** property of **CordovaView** control (on MainPage.xaml), for example

```
<my:CordovaView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                   StartPageUri = "http://mydomain/mypage.html"
                   Margin="0,0,0,0"  
                   Name="PGView" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```