# Phonegap 3.2 windows phone 7 - External url

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I want to launch the app with an external url of my site(have a mobile site, web application). Let's say cnn.com. Had a look at

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430196/using-phonegap-cordova-on-windows-phone-7-with-external-url)

When I do it all it tells me is :

```
Adding feature.value=Globalization
Adding feature.value=InAppBrowser
Adding feature.value=Notification
GapBrowser_NavigationFailed :: http://cnn.com/
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction. What am I doing wrong, the exception doesn't have lot of info and looking at other forums doesn't look like its cors issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Open up the WMAppManifest.xml in the Properties folder and if you are in Visual Studio you will see three tabs. Check that on the Capabilities tab you have ID_CAP_NETWORKING checked.

In addition you may need the following in your config.xml:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Comment: I was getting this error, and adding ID_CAP_NETWORKING fixed it.